# Enabeling the 'perspective with ortho faces' in viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge

I can currently do:

```
this.viewer.navigation.toOrthographic()
```

and

```
this.viewer.navigation.toPerspective()
```

Is there a way that I could also use the perspective with ortho faces and change the current viewer into that on the go?

I get that there are view_types (https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/globals/VIEW_TYPES/) I could set up on initialize, but i would like to change this option after model load without having to use the view cube.

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood what you are after correctly then it's possible to call shots for viewcube as an extension programmatically (since v7.x and onwards), say for example:

```
//wait after model is rendered ...
const viewCubeUI = NOP_VIEWER.getExtension("Autodesk.ViewCubeUi")
viewCubeUI.setViewType(Autodesk.Viewing.Private.VIEW_TYPES.PERSPECTIVE_ORTHO_FACES)
```

See documentation [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Extensions/ViewCubeUi/) for details...

Comment: Thank you for the answer Bryan, but sorry, it was not the answer I was getting at (also realized my question was slightly wrong.
I will try to rephrase:
In view cube you have options for 3 different view types; ortho, perspective, and perspective with ortho fees.
The first two I can change my viewer into with the code in my question (correct from original question), but the last I have not found a way to call. This is what I was hoping for.